# How to aggregate all values in a pandas dataframe columns in 2 values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe contains some columns. Each columns have some differents values. See the image.

[image]

In col1 I have that the value 1 is more frequent than others, so, I need to transform this column to have values 1 and more then 1.

How can I do that?

My goals here is transforme this column in a categorical column but I have no idea how can I do that.

The output expected is something like the next image:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, numpy.where, df.map, list comprehension...? Your question should include your sample input and expected output as text, not as an image or link, as well as code for what you've tried based on your own research, to make a [mcve] so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Could you provide the expected output as well as the input in a [text format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Edit your post to contain this information.

Comment: Thank you so much for aswer me @G.Anderson, I have no idea how can I do what I need!

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, I will change my question and put an example of output... Thank you so much for answer me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clip function on column:

```
df["col1"].clip(upper=2)

0     1
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Seeling. This function clip() help me a lot!